# after updating protolib and protoc, gRPC doesnt work anymore

Tags: php, grpc, protoc

Yesterday my ubuntu made update (from log)
Grpc for PHP

> Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.567'
>   Upgrade: libprotoc-dev:amd64 (3.5.0-0~maarten0+artful,
>   3.5.0.1-0~maarten0+artful), libprotoc15:amd64 (3.5.0-0~maarten0+artful, 3.5.0.1-0~maarten0+artful),
>   gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu2,
>   3.26.1-0ubuntu2.17.10.1), gnome-software:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.1-0ubuntu2.17.10.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (62.0.3202.94-1, 63.0.3239.84-1), protobuf-compiler:amd64 (3.5.0-0~maarten0+artful, 3.5.0.1-0~maarten0+artful), ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.1-0ubuntu2.17.10.1), libprotobuf-lite15:amd64 (3.5.0-0~maarten0+artful, 3.5.0.1-0~maarten0+artful),
>   gnome-software-plugin-flatpak:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu2,
>   3.26.1-0ubuntu2.17.10.1), libprotobuf15:amd64 (3.5.0-0~maarten0+artful, 3.5.0.1-0~maarten0+artful),
>   libprotobuf-dev:amd64 (3.5.0-0~maarten0+artful,
>   3.5.0.1-0~maarten0+artful), gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.1-0ubuntu2.17.10.1)

and when rebooted I'm unable to make any Grpc request I do have extension=grpc.so in my php.ini file and same code worked yesterday, I tried also to update it in my composer file, also tried to reinstall Grpc as well as recreate classes from my proto file. For some reason it just won't work anymore.

I always get same response

> message: "Class 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials' not found"

any ideas how to fix it(or what went wrong)?

EDIT: I use docker for local server - is it possible that 2 different versions collide now?

Answer (score 1):

It's really strange because based on your log, only protobuf upgrade from 3.5.0 to 3.5.0.1 and gnome-software upgrade. It seems they won't break grpc. I installed those packages and then installed grpc-1.7.0 and protobuf-3.5.0.1 by "sudo pecl install grpc(protobuf)" but they works well.

The error "Class 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials' not found" most likely means the grpc.so extension is not loaded correctly. We should locate where the problem is. You can try to

- run php program with "-d extension=/path/to/grpc.so" directly or restart php to check whether is it the problem with php.
- [run example](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php.html#download-the-example) or [install grpc.so by building from the source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/php#build-from-source) to find out is it the problem with gRPC.

Comment: also I'm new to docker, since my project is there... is it now a problem in docker env or laptop? since in docker nothing is changed for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone has similar issue
Solution to my issue was inside docker. For whatever reason my installation of grpc was lost

I fixed it with connecting to docker bash and installing grpc again with

> pecl install grpc

and readded extensions=grpc.so in my php.ini file

EDIT: same problem happens every time I change antyhing in docker-compose.yaml